# Angular9: project ng new -> Disk 0(C:) is reaching 100%

Tags: angular, hard-drive, new-project

I am new to Angular. Whenever I create a new project my C disk is hitting 100% and CMD is freezing by showing Installing packages...
I have waited more than an hour but still intalling.

Why C: disk reaching 100%. How can I solve this problem?
[image: 1]

I use my PC for mostly DotNet projects. I use both VS2017 and VS2019. Did not feel any problem while using them.

Comment: maybe you need to run cmd with administrator privilege or the path is too long try on another partition with short path 

Comment: @malbarmavi I have tried:
1) Run CMD as administrator 
&
2) Used shorter path as C:\
Neither way did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had slow&old PC with only HDD, no SSD

Sometime later I got better PC and never had such issues after that